# Subgroup and conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $G$ be a group and $C_x$ a conjugacy class, with $|C_x|=n$. prove that $\exists H\leq G$ with H being a subgroup of G, that $|G/H|=n$

It easy to proof that this happens with G being a finite group but my problem starts when G is a infinite group because I cannot apply Lagrange theorem and because of that I don't have any ideia of who is H

Any hints?

Comment: What does Lagrange's theorem have to do with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$F_x = \{f \in G, \; fxf^{-1} = x \}; \tag 1$

that is, $F_x \subset G$ is the set of group elements which fix $x \in G$ under conjugation; it is easy to see that $F_x$ is in fact a subgroup of $G$, since for

$a, b \in F_x \tag 2$

we have

$(ab)x(ab)^{-1} = (ab)x(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = a(bxb^{-1})a^{-1} = axa^{-1} = a, \tag 3$

and the identity $e \in G$ is clearly in $F_x$:

$exe^{-1} = exe = xe = x; \tag 4$

and

$a \in F_x \Longleftrightarrow axa^{-1} = x \Longleftrightarrow a^{-1}xa = x \Longleftrightarrow a^{-1} \in F_x. \tag 5$

Now consider any coset $gF_x$ of $F_x$, where $g \in G$; for $f \in F_x$ we have

$(gf)x(gf)^{-1} = (gf)x(f^{-1}g^{-1}) = g(fxg^{-1})g^{-1} = gxg^{-1}, \tag 6$

which shows that elements $gf \in gF_x$ all take $x$ to $gxg^{-1}$ under conjugation; in fact, the conjugate $gxg^{-1}$ only depends on the coset $gF_x$ and not upon its representative $g$; for if

$g_1F_x = g_2F_x, \tag 7$

then

$g_1 = g_1e = g_2 f_1 \tag 8$

for some $f_1 \in F_x$, whence

$g_1xg_1^{-1} = (g_2f_1)x(g_2f_1)^{-1} = (g_2f_1)x(f_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}) = g_2(f_1xf_1^{-1})g_2^{-1} = g_2xg_2^{-1}; \tag 9$

it follows then, that there is a well-defined map

$\phi: G/F_x \to C_x; \tag{10}$

$\phi$ is injective, for if

$\phi(g_1F_x) = \phi(g_2F_x), \tag{11}$

then

$g_1xg_1^{-1} = g_2xg_2^{-1} \Longrightarrow (g_2^{-1}g_1)x(g_1^{-1}g_2) = x \Longrightarrow (g_2^{-1}g_1)x(g_2^{-1}g_1)^{-1} = x$
$\Longrightarrow g_2^{-1}g_1 \in F_x \Longrightarrow g_1 = g_2f, \; f \in F_x \Longrightarrow g_1F_x = g_2fF_x = g_2F_x; \tag{12}$

$\phi$ is also surjective, for

$\phi(gF_x) = gxg^{-1} \tag{13}$

for any conjugate of $x$.  Since $\phi$ is a bijection, we conclude that

$\vert G/F_x \vert = \vert C_x \vert = n, \tag{14}$

$OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Notice that $C_x$ is an *orbit* of $x$ under the conjugation action of $G$ (on its own elements).  Some elements of $G$ *stabilize* $x$ when they conjugate $x$ and some elements of $G$ push $x$ to a different member of this *orbit*.